# sending php generated data to html elements

Tags: php, html

Lets say I have html page that has 3 elements. Content of those elements should be taken from data base and just put there. Now, I can take data from db, I made my html and css styling, only problem I have is I don't know how to update html page with php data taken from Db. I don't want to use echo since that will give me separate page, I thought about using php to open that html file and rewrite it dynamically but that seems bit extreme. Any suggestion ?

Comment: What do you mean echo gives you separate page?

Comment: It appears there are some very basic concepts of php which are not clearly understood here. I suggest you follow a few tutorials first to get familiar with the language and how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the extension of your html page as .php
Where you want to put data do something like this -

```
<?php
    // write your select query
    $val = "data retrieved from php"
?>
```

Where you want to place it in the DOM, do something like this -

```
<div><?=$val?></div>
```